# Python Review: Why doesn't code 1 produce same result as code 2?

Tags: python

Why does code 1 output 28 (not what I want) but code 2 outputs [7, 14, 21, 28] (what I want)?

```
#Code 1
def dog_years(age):
    return age * 7

def my_pets_age(func, param_list):
    for i in param_list:
        func(i)    
    return func(i)
    
dog_age = my_pets_age(dog_years, [1, 2, 3, 4]) 

print(dog_age)
```

Is there a way for me to write this so that I don't need to create a result variable with an empty array?

```
#Code 2
def dog_years(age):
    return age * 7

def my_pets_age(func, param_list):
    result = []
    for i in param_list:
        result.append(func(i))
    return result

dog_age = my_pets_age(dog_years, [1, 2, 3, 4]) 

print(dog_age)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code 1, you're not storing the value returned by `func(i)` anywhere on each iteration. The value is computed and then just thrown away. Then, once the loop is done, the value of `i` is `4` because that's the last value in the `param_list` so you return `func(4)` which is 28.

In the second code, you're actually storing the intermediate values by appending them to the result array.

You can rewrite the second code as:

```py
def my_pets_age(func, param_list):
    return [func(i) for i in param_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code #1. Where do you use the result of the `func` calls from the loop? (Hint: You don't)

There are only four ways information leaves a function:

1. Through the `return` value
2. (For generators) Through a `yield` expression
3. Via an exception being raised
4. By changes to external state (storing to globals, attributes of outside objects or `self`, etc.)

The only one of those that applies in either example is #1. In the first block of code, you ignore *everything* you do in the loop aside from the assignment to `i`, so all it does is return `func(i)` where `i` is the last value looped over. In the second block of code, you build a `list` of all the results and return that, so you get all of the results, not just the last one.